# Как показать или сохранить картинку Pillow, используя класс

Tags: python, классы, pillow

Есть класс с одним из методов, который должен рисовать или сохранять картинку при помощи библиотеки Pillow. Как правильно это записать?

```
class Rectangle:
    """smth"""
    def __init__(self):
    ...
    def image_gen(self):
        background = Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), self.color())
        background.show()
```

Comment: переведите на русский язык

Comment: Есть класс с одним из методов, который должен рисовать или сохранять картинку при помощи библиотеки Pillow. Как правильно это записать?